# Time required to observe electrostatic phenonmenon

Tags: electrostatics, time

So I had to do this project on Van De Graff generators and explain the mechanism of how it works so I thought id start it by explaining how charge is induced on a spherical conductor due to another spherical conductor inside it.
Now what we learnt in class was charges get induced cause the field inside a conductor must always be zero otherwise there would be current inside (which would be free-energy* which is impossible) So using this property id like to explain the magnitude of charges being induced. This requires me to have an external spherical conductor or radius 'R' and an inner one of smaller radius 'then distribute charges across the surface such that it satisfies the no field condition and then increase the charge on the inner conductor which gradually increases the charge present on the external conductor and then just bring that close to a grounded ball and done.

But then I got curious,
How long does it actually take to observe phenomenon like induction of charges between two conductors or just induction in general? nanoseconds? picoseconds? Is there a mathematical relation between the kinetic energy of the free electrons present in the conductor that can move to another point across a potential difference or something mathematical about it or is it completely observational? What about other phenomenon like triboelectric effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum time required would be $t=L/c$ where $L$ is the largest length involved and $c$ is the speed of light. If there are stray capacitances and non-zero resistances then it will take longer. A better estimate would be $t=5\ RC$ where $R$ is the largest non-zero resistance and $C$ is the largest stray capacitance. The 5 is just a rule of thumb that after 5 time constants the item is at steady state.

Comment: If not a highly conductive metal, the dielectric relaxation time can be one more time constant to consider.